# I have a question about solving this express.js problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I just started studying about Node.js with Express.js framework. 
I tried so hard but I have no idea how to solve these questions... I hope you guys can help me to solve those questions. Thank you :)

This is my problem :

1. DELETE /book?title=:book_title

   - always returns 204 Not Content status code even if the book is not present in the datastore.
   - no response body.
2. GET /books

   - returns 200 Success status code.
   - returns list of all books.
   - return format must be JSON: 
     { "books": [{ "author":"joe", "title":"MyBook", "pages":234, "quality":"new"}, ... ] }
3. PUT /book

   - updates a single book on the list based on the title.
   - returns 200 Success status code when it finds the book and updates it successfully.
   - returns a single book formatted in JSON as the response body:
     ex. { "book": { "author":"joe", "title":"MyBook", "pages":234, "quality":"new" }}
     as long the body has the book and all its fields, the format does not matter.
   - for the PUT, please have your application accept a request body of content-type JSON and treat the title as the identifier when looking for the book
     for example, your cURL might look like: curl localhost:3000/book -X PUT -d '{"title":"...", "author":"...", ... }' -H 'content-type: application/json'
   - the request body can contain any of the attributes of a book, so if a matching attribute has a new value in the request body, update it, otherwise, ignore it
     for example, if the request body is {"title":"currentTitle", "author":"newtitle","nonexistentattribute":"nonexistentvalue"}, the datastore would update the book titled "currentTitle" with the new "author" value, but ignore the "nonexistentattribute" since that doesn't exist as an attribute for a book.
   - if the title is not found in the in-memory datastore, return a 404 status response code and whatever body you want to the user.

---

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var books = {
  "books": [{
      "author": "joe",
      "title": "MyBook",
      "pages": 234,
      "quality": "new"
    },
    {
      "author": "kevin",
      "title": "YourBook",
      "pages": 432,
      "quality": "old"
    }
  ]
}

app.delete('/book?title=:book_title', (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.params.book_title);
  res.status(204);
});

app.get('/books', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(books));
});

app.put('/book', (req, res) => {
  // have no idea..
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("listening on port 3000"));
```

Comment: Not sure if express parses the query string part of the url for route parameters seeing as you could use `req.query.book_title` to get it. Try making it part of the path, eg `/book/:book_title` on frontend the url would be something like `http://example.com/book/somebook` see if that makes a difference

Comment: @PatrickEvans I tried but still "Cannot GET /book/:book_title"...

Comment: ... actually im confused on the actual problem...are all the bullet points a list of problems or a list of requirements

Comment: @PatrickEvans it's all requirements for each number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated code that will get you required results. I will suggest to do some reading.

READ: [How to create a REST API with Express.js in Node.js](https://www.robinwieruch.de/node-express-server-rest-api) and [REST API with Node and Express in 5 minutes](https://dev.to/lenmorld/quick-rest-api-with-node-and-express-in-5-minutes-336j). You can also check the [Express API](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html) to get a detailed understanding.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hi, This is Yi Wan's workpage")
});

// keep this as array of objects
// and not an object of array of objects
// TIP: it's best to keep as object of objects
var books = [{
      "author": "joe",
      "title": "MyBook",
      "pages": 234,
      "quality": "new"
    },
    {
      "author": "kevin",
      "title": "YourBook",
      "pages": 432,
      "quality": "old"
    }
  ]

app.delete('/book/:title', (req, res) => {
  // find the book and delete it
  for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    if (books[i].title == req.params.title) {
      books.splice(i, 1);
      res.status(200).end(); // end the response
    }
  }

  // book not found, so send proper error code
  res.status(404).end(); // resource does not exist
});

app.get('/books', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(books));
});

app.put('/book/:title', (req, res) => {
  // find the book and update it
  for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    if (books[i].title == req.params.title) {
      books.splice(i, 1); // delete the old book
      books.push(req.body); // add the new book
      res.status(200).end(); // end the response
    }
  }

  // book not found, so send proper error code
  res.status(404).end(); // resource does not exist
});


app.listen(3000, () => console.log("listening on port 3000"));
```